# how to restore iptables after iptables -F?

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables

I used `iptables -F` on my machine, and what can I do to recover the iptables into the default without rebooting my machine?

I restarted the iptables service and it failed, and I can't find iptables under `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`

Answer (score 0):

The iptables-restore command is used to restore the iptables rule-set that was saved with the iptables-save command. It takes all the input from standard input and can't load from files as of writing this, unfortunately. This is the command syntax for iptables-restore:

```
iptables-restore [-c] [-n]
```

[More details here](https://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/chunkyhtml/x1882.html)

Comment: I do know this command, but since I never save my iptable with iptables-save, so I can't find any file to restore, I am wondering if their is a default iptables stored somewhere, so I can just load this iptables would be fine.

Comment: @Unnikrishnan you _can_ load files using standard redirection, e.g., `iptables-restore < /path/to/file`. Alternatively, use the `iptables-apply` command.

Comment: @dspjm what Linux distro are you using? Anyways, try `grep -r "*filter" /etc/*` to find the files (generated by iptables-save)

Comment: @pepoluan using your method, I found a file suspicious /etc/ppp/firewall-masq,  which is a script to add rules into iptables when system boot. I am using fedora BTW

Comment: @dspjm Then I wager that file actually contains the iptables rules dump. Can you put that in a pastebin somewhere so I can take a peek?

Answer (score -1):

Your system is probably using `firewalld`, so you'll probably want to run `systemctl restart firewalld`.

Comment: Given the info provided, what the heck makes you think that?

Comment: Seeing the question again after 3 years, truth be said, most probably from the top of my head.

Comment: Just a bit out of left field, but fair enough.